# Virtual Method logic not working C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, methods, virtual

I'm working through an example in the book`Pro C# and the .NET Platform` and I'm making a mistake somewhere that I can't see.  The program compiles and runs, but the `Manager` object in this example isn't having the right value of 'StockOptions' returned.  In an effort of concision, I'm going to try to only post the relevant code because this example is all about class hierarchies and there's like six different classes.  The virtual method `GiveBonus` in the `Employee` class isn't being correctly overridden in the `Manager` class.

```
class Manager : Employee
{
    private int numberOfOpts;
    //the properties are inherited from Employee

    public int StockOptions { get; set; }

    //***METHODS*** this is returns the StockOptions amount as it is in the
    //  constructor, there's no logic being applied
    public override void GiveBonus(float amount)
    {
        base.GiveBonus(amount);
        Random r = new Random();
        numberOfOpts += r.Next(500);    
    }

    public override void DisplayStats()
    {
        base.DisplayStats();
        Console.WriteLine("you have {0} stock options", StockOptions);
    }

    public Manager() { }


    public Manager(string fullName, int age, int empID, float currPay, 
        string ssn, int numbofOpts) : base(fullName, age, empID, currPay, ssn)

    {
        ID = empID;
        Age = age;
        Name = fullName;
        Pay = currPay;
        StockOptions = numbofOpts;
    }
}
```

snippet from my Main() method

```
Manager chucky = new Manager("chucky", 50, 92, 100000, "333-33-3333", 9000);
chucky.GiveBonus(300);
chucky.DisplayStats();
Console.WriteLine();
```

I made a mistake while asking the question.  What I should have asked is why I have to use

```
Console.WriteLine("you have {0} stock options", numbOfOpts);
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("you have {0} stock options", StockOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not meant to add a random number to 9000 - it's meant to give a random number of *stock options* as well as the "base" pay bonus:

```
public override void GiveBonus(float amount)
{
    base.GiveBonus(amount);
    Random r = new Random();

    // Note numberOfOpts, not currPay
    numberOfOpts += r.Next(500);
}
```

Unfortunately, as we've got two separate fields - one created by an automatically implemented property - it won't *actually* update the value of `StockOptions`... it's not clear whether this is due to your editing, or whether it's a mistake in the book. (There are various other things I dislike about this code, but hey...)

Comment: It's actually in the book :).  When I change `StockOptions` to a field that's in the class, `numberOfOpts` it returns a random number.  So the private backing field will `never` be updated in an implementation like this?  Could you also expound on why you disfavor this code?  I'm just learning all this stuff and this is straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: The field backing `StockOptions` certainly won't be changed automatically by setting a different field, no. Oh dear. As for other problems - the names are horrible, the parameterless constructor seems like a bad idea, there's no validation, I'd expect various properties to be set by the base constructor (and immutable, for the most part). If the comment above `GiveBonus` is verbatim too, that makes no sense. Ick, basically.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what I should have been asking.  The code is verbatim, but the comment was my pitiful attempt at god-knows-what.